# Calculation of $\limsup \vert a_k \vert ^{1/k}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_k$ a sequence defined by:

$a_k=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}$ if $k=3n-1$ and $a_k=0$ in other case.

Find $\limsup\sqrt[k]{\vert a_k \vert}$

My idea is to try to find some sequence that converges to $a\neq 0$, but I can't find it. Any hint?

Comment: I assume you want $|a_k|^{1/k}$ not $|a_k|^{1/n}$.  Can you do: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(3n-1)^{1/(3n-1)}$$

Comment: Why $\text{log}(3n-1)$?

Comment: Maybe better $\log(n)^{1/(3n-1)}$

Comment: This limit is $\text{limsup}$? Although I still don't know how to calculate it. Graphing it seems to be something greater than 1

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by GEdgar, your main interest is $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\log(n))^{(1/n)}$. To compute such a limit, it is always nice to write it as

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\log(n))^{(1/n)} = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{\log((\log(n))^{(1/n)})}=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{\log((\log(n))}{n}}$$

Now you can conclude because you know the asymptotics of $\frac{\log((\log(n))}{n}$.

Comment: $\lim \frac{ln(ln(x))}{x} = 1$?

Comment: Does $\log$ have linear growth ?